# Why does removing () for ruby conditionals throwing error?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

```
if (ax_response = OpenID::AX::FetchResponse.from_success_response openid_response)
```

The above line if i remove the ( ) paranthesis it throws a syntax error ..Unexpected tIdentifier . Why ?

Comment: Can you post the whole exception?

Comment: Which identifier is the problem? Does it work if you put parentheses around the `.from_success_response` call only, or around `openid_response` only?

Comment: Are you trying to assign the result to `ax_response` or test for equality?

Comment: Have you tried calling a model without any colon `:` in their name? Something like `if user = User.first` Edit: I see it, you need to use parentheses for your method `from_success_response(openid_response)`

Comment: You got it right . Thank you @MrYoshiji

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ruby's pretty good at picking up arbitrary syntax, but without brackets to coach it sometimes it can't figure out your intention. In this case you have two choices.

Brackets around the `if` statement:

```
if (var = method arg)
end
```

Brackets around the argument:

```
if var = method(arg)
end
```

Without some sort of coaching it's not going to be able to lock on to the precise meaning of your statement. If you come from a background like Perl, C++ or JavaScript where brackets are not optional this is never an issue. Ruby is just unusually forgiving.

Comment: yep that answers it . Thank you @MrYoshiji